# complex integral with logarithmic derivative of $\zeta$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, complex-integration, upper-lower-bounds

I want to prove that for any $x\geq 2$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s)&=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}\frac{\log(x/n)}{\log x}+\frac{1}{\log x}\left(\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s)\right)^{\prime}+\frac{1}{\log x}\sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho-s}}{(\rho-s)^2}\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad-\frac{x^{1-s}}{(1-s)^2\log x}+\frac{1}{\log x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{-2k-s}}{(2k+s)^2}.
\end{split}
$$
The idea of the proof is to consider to express $\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}$ as a Dirichlet series and make use of the identity (for $c>0$)
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}x^s\frac{ds}{s^2}=
\begin{cases}
\log x &\text{if }x\geq 1,\\
0 &\text{if } 0\leq x <1.
\end{cases}
$$
Indeed in this way, setting $c=\max\{1,2-\sigma\}$ and interchanging the order of summation and integration (which is justified b absolute convergence), we get
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s+w)\frac{x^w}{w^2}\,dw&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^{s+w}}\right]\frac{x^w}{w^2}\,dw\\
        &=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^w\frac{dw}{w^2}\\
        &=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}\log(x/n).
\end{split}
$$
Now I would to estimate the integral in another way: moving the line of integration to the left ($c\to \infty$) and using Cauchy residue theorem.
The residue I get is
$$ 
-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s)\log x-\left(\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s)\right)^{\prime}-\sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho-s}}{(\rho-s)^2}+\frac{x^{1-s}}{(1-s)^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{-2k-s}}{(2k+s)^2}.
$$
Therefore I would get my claim if I was able to show that the other integrals go to zero. How can I show it? Let
$$
f(w)=-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s+w)\frac{x^w}{w^2}
$$
I have to fix $K>0$ and show that
$$
\int_{c+iK}^{-K+iK}f(w)\,dw,\qquad \int_{-K+iK}^{-K-iK}f(w)\,dw,\qquad \int_{-K-iK}^{c-iK}f(w)\,dw,
$$
all tend to zero as $K\to \infty$. Do you have any hint on how to proceed? Which bound should I use? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is explained in every text, the difficulty is to find a sequence $T_l$ such that $\lim_{l \to \infty} \int_{2+iT_l}^{-1+iT_l} \frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \frac{x^s}{s^2}ds = 0$, you know it exists by the density of zeros $O(T \ln T)$ and $\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) = \sum_{|\rho-s| < 1} \frac{1}{s-\rho} + O(\ln t)$, once you have it $\sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n) (1-\frac{\ln n}{\ln x})=\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \frac{x^s}{s^2}ds =\lim_{l \to \infty} \int_{\partial ([2-T_l,2] +i [-T_l,T_l])}\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \frac{x^s}{s^2}ds = \lim_{l \to \infty} \sum Res(...)$.

Comment: In which text I can find it explained in detail?

Comment: Also $\sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n) (1-\frac{\ln n}{\ln x}) x^{-2}$  is integrable and continuous and so is its Mellin transform (on vertical lines) so the Mellin inversion converges locally uniformly for every $x>0$. What makes a difference is that for $x \le 1$ you'll apply the residue theorem to $\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \frac{x^s}{s^2}ds =-\lim_{l \to \infty} \int_{\partial ([2,2+\color{red}{+} T_l] +i [-T_l,T_l])}\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \frac{x^s}{s^2}ds = 0$, obtaining $\sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho^2}1_{x>1}$ in the explicit formula

Comment: can I use the arguments of Chapter 12 - Multiplicative umber Theory by Montgomery and Vaughan? Overthere they work with the integral of $-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s)\frac{x^s}{s}$